# MapView crashing

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I've been adding MapView into my ViewController. Code as below:

```
MapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = [[myStore.Location objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
region.center.longitude = [[myStore.Location objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta  = .0015;
span.longitudeDelta = .0015;
region.span = span;
[MapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

`myStore.Location` is an array with coordinates. XCode just crashes the app and return the error at `[MapView setRegion:region animated:YES];` which i assume that it cannot init the mapview, can anyone help?

Comment: Try to obtain more data from the crash log. Add exception breakpoint to help you. Try to also add a breakpoint right after alloc and init of the MKMapView to see that it is initialized.

Comment: What exactly do you see in the debugger as result of that crash?

Comment: A crash on setRegion usually means the region is invalid.  Log the values you are getting from myStore and putting in the region's center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've resolved my problem... the latitude and longitude was being reversed. `[myStore.Location objectAtIndex:0]` should be the longitude and `[myStore.Location objectAtIndex:1]` should be the latitude... silly me.

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted. It will be helpful for you and the Stack overflow community. Read this for more details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Also add crash log/error details to your question. That will help others in future to know exactly what your problem exactly was which you have answered yourself!